# Not getting return value

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to get a return value and it keeps giving me an error. 
I am trying to grab the "roleid" after the username has been validated by sending it the username-- I can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
public string ValidateRole(string sUsername)
{
    string matchstring = "SELECT  roleid FROM tblUserRoles WHERE UserName='" +      sUsername +"'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(matchstring);
    cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=samplename;Integrated Security=True");
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(dt);

    string match;
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            match = row["roleid"].ToString();
            return match;
        }
    }  
    else
    {  
        match = "fail";
        return match;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: It looks like you are only expecting one row to be returned, so there's no point in looping through the rows, but I doubt that is the cause of the error. Which line is throwing the exception and what is the message?

Comment: You need to provide details of the exception you are getting in order to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: I have several "roleid"'s in the database. So, I am expecting whichever row matches the 'sUsername' --The error I'm getting is that "not all paths return a value" such that it isn't receiving the return value from my string when I am telling it to return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Not all code paths return a value" error you are seeing is a compiler error, not a runtime error, so the problem is with your C# code not being correct.

In this case it is because you have a return statement in a foreach loop and the compiler is not quite smart enough to see that your code would go down the 'else' path if there were no rows in the datatable. I.e. the compiler cannot see that the 'If (true)' branch will always return a value.

Best practice is to always have a return statement at the end of the function, and to initialize you variables ('match' is not initialized). If you return part way through, your code is less readable too.

The simplest fix is:

```
 public string ValidateRole(string sUsername)
   {

       string matchstring = "SELECT  roleid FROM tblUserRoles WHERE UserName='" +      sUsername +"'";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(matchstring);
       cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=samplename;Integrated Security=True");
       cmd.Connection.Open();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

       SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
       sda.Fill(dt);

       string match = "fail";
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
       foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
       {
           match = row["roleid"].ToString();
        return match;
       }              

    }  

    return "fail";

   }
```

However, there are several other issues with the code you may not be aware of:

1. You have a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability that makes your
   application completely insecure. This is because you have
   concatenated SQL strings to make a query rather than writing a
   [parametized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).
2. You should get in the habit of using a [ADO.NET DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx) over a DataAdapters and DataTables. Or better, avoid DataTables altogether as
   they are legacy. Use Linq2Sql or Entity Framework for your data
   access layer and you will write far less code.
3. You should seriously consider using [ASP.NET Membersip API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx) for your authorization and roles etc. If you did that, your function would not even be required - you'd just write: Roles.IsUserInRole(sUserName, "User") to check whether a user is in a certain role.
4. When you use a resource that implements IDisposable, like SQLConnection, you should wrap its use in a [using() {} block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so that you always release the resource as soon as possible.

Comment: Remove the `else` statement altogether.

Comment: UPVOTE FOR YOU!! I can't upvote yet because my reputation isn't 15.. it worked like a charm and I was able to send through my session with the roleid!! Thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason for the foreach loop? Could you just rewrite it as `retrun dt.rows[0]["roleId"].ToString();`

Comment: @scottO If this answer is the right one, show your appreciation by hitting the "tick" button underneath the voting buttons to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the connection string is invalid:

```
SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog="mydatabase";Integrated Security=True");
```

should be:

```
SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=\"mydatabase\";Integrated Security=True");
```

Notice that the quotes are escaped in the Initial Catalog value. If this is not the issue, post your exception.

Comment: The code looks more like he's replaced the db name for the sake of the sample. If it were as you suggest the code would not compile.

Comment: Yes, I just commented that for the sample. Thank you for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
string match;
```

to

```
string match = null;
```

If the `foreach` never finds a match, the variable `match` never gets instantiated.  The compilation error is trying to tell you this.